# Pycharm can't recognize apps that added using manage.py startapp django

Tags: python, django, pycharm

when I add app to my django project by using 'python manage.py startapp [app_name]' and add app_name to my INSTALLED_APPS in django settings pycharm can't recognized imports from that apps (when I run my server, it runs without error).

What should I do?
I upload some images below for more details:

Django settings:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2OTX.png)]
Project Structure:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIl2b.png)]
Imports: 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDrEx.png)]
My apps
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KCme.png)]

my working directory is like this:
-ToDoApp-DRF-CBV[PyCharm Working Directory]
--core
----core
----manage.py
----accounts
----blog
--gitignore
--...

when I change my working directory to 'core' it can find modules (which is normal) but I can't do that because I have VCS in my current working directory and other code editors like VSCode find my apps for imports and only PyCharm can't recognized them.

Comment: Try Right-click on **core**, Mark Directory  as > Sources Root

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @monim says in the comments, I right-click on core, Mark Directory as > Sources Root, after that PyCharm is able to locate my apps.